# Rootstock not working

Tags: kernel, 13.04, compiling, arm, qemu

I am getting this error:

```
./rootstock: 1000: ./rootstock: cannot create /tmp/tmp.C7sAyhcAxf/tmpmount/etc/fstab: Directory nonexistent
```

Ubuntu 13.04

When I want to create simple qemu image with this command:

```
 sudo ./rootstock --fqdn qemu-test --login qemu --password qemupwd --notarball
```

Im using Ubuntu 13.04

Any info?

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is the fact that the default repository is not there.

this is an archive that works still: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/.

here is what my cmd looks like

```
sudo ./rootstock --fqdn myhostname --login ubuntu --password temppwd --imagesize 2G -m http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ -d jaunty --seed dpkg-dev,debhelper,libgtk2.0-dev,gnome-settings-daemon-dev,libgconf2-dev,libglade2-dev,libxklavier12-dev,libgnomekbd-dev,libasound2-dev
```

so just add `-m http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` and it works great!

Answer (score -1):

Please install the `fakeroot` package by:

```
sudo apt-get install fakeroot
```

Comment: Why should op install fakeroot?